# Abnormally Bandwidth utilization goes high what should I do

Tags: internet, bandwidth, fortigate

We have 20 MBPS Internet lease line, suddnly my bandwidth utilization reached peak that causes slowness of internet.

I am not able to trace whether the problem is and what should I do?

Please assist me.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture all network traffic from your internet connection to understand what traffic is causing it.  Until you know what causes it, you cannot take effective action to stop it happening.

There are various ways of performing the capture but they depend on your specific network hardware and toplogy.

Comment: is there any tool for that?

Comment: If your edge router is a L3 switch then you will be able to define a monitor port, otherwise you will need to tap your Internet line.  You send the monitor traffic to some sort of capture device, most easily provided by a PC running Wireshark software.